# Where is the return type of typeof defined?

Tags: typescript

The result of the `typeof` operator is typed (union of all the values it can be, like `'string' | 'number' | ...`)

Is this union type exposed somewhere? I checked in the `lib.*.d.ts`, but couldn't find anything.

Or is this type not exposed to users?

Comment: Can you be more precise? Even if type is not exposed we can still name it by `type MyType = typeof x`.

Comment: @MaciejSikora I'm not sure how to be more precise, I'd like to reuse the type that `typeof` returns. It's a union type of string literals, like `'string' | 'number' | 'object' ...`. If there's a named type like `TypeofResult`, I'd like to reuse it, instead of defining this type myself.

Comment: How do you use `typeof` operator? Because `type O = typeof;` is illegal

Comment: This is how you can get primitives: `type Primitives = keyof any`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a predefined type that you can access which will give you a union of all the possible results of an expression with the `typeof` operator.

You can of course create your own. The full list is:

```
type TypeofResult = "string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"

let foo: unknown;

let bar: TypeofResult = typeof foo; // Allowed
let baz: 'object' = typeof foo; // Error, because there are more possible results
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEHsBmAlCBnArgG2FAvFAETrABOAlgHYDmRUAPsVZgLYBGEZ9TR7FNasB7F2CBNggBDKiJIgOEuZioATCEmoRVchOwBWEAMbDGxJCpMUEsgFC3JeJOIBcUFQGsqCAO5UA3PaOUOxSZG5wkMhoWLgEUKBRSFDOCP5QAPQZUACC2Ni+2g4QeKEAXm4A5HqGJpXxiYjJqelZUACiZGQIZAA0IcZSmOjQwAAWXNBh0Kw90GAI6OgU7JJQZBg4wOhAA)